# Get all local variables or available methods from irb?

Tags: ruby, reflection, irb

When I go into irb and type in a command that does not exist I get an error stating

```
"undefined local variable or method 'my_method' for main:Object (NameError)"
```

Is there a way to just get a list of what local variables or methods ARE available? This would be really useful for exploring ruby.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Look for methods in the Kernel, Object and Module : e.g. [local_variables](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-local_variables), [instance_methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods), [instance_variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables).

Other great methods in there. [inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-inspect) is another one.

Comment: @sawa, inspect will show instance_variables too (i.e. unless it has been overridden for a class to show something else instead)

Comment: can someone explain how this guy gets the prompt: "show all available 152) methods?" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_9H1WPV2Ws#t=0m15s

Comment: @lukemh, type `[1,2].` into `irb` and press `TAB` twice. The feature in general is called *completion* / *auto-completion*.

Answer (score 16):

Great answers.
As you explore, you have these at your disposal:

```
obj.private_methods 
obj.public_methods 
obj.protected_methods 
obj.singleton_methods
```

and

```
MyClass.private_instance_methods 
MyClass.protected_instance_methods 
MyClass.public_instance_methods
```

Usage like :

```
obj.public_methods.sort
```

Can make review easier too.

Some special cases exist like

```
String.instance_methods(false).sort
```

... will give you only the instance methods defined in the String class, omitting the classes it inherited from any ancestors.  As I expect you know, you can see more here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/ but it's not as fun as inspecting and reflecting in irb.

Happy exploring -

Perry

Answer (score 6):

To find out instance variables, you can use `Kernel#instance_variables` as Zabba pointed out.

For methods available on an object, I use `my_object.methods - Object.methods` to find out what non-obvious methods are available to my object. This narrows down the list and is considerably easy to read.

Comment: You should probably change that to `my_object.methods.sort - Object.new.methods` -- as it stands, you're subtracting `Object`'s class methods from the list of `my_object`'s instance methods.

Comment: True. However in Ruby, `Object.class` is `Class` which is an instance of the class `Class`, so it still has the methods from `Object.methods`.