# Inspect variables in IronRuby scope

Tags: .net, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

I want browse (and inspect) scope variables of ironruby scope.

If i execute:

```
a = 15
b = 16
c = a * b
```

I want to enumerate "`a`, `b`, `c`" and get their value on demand.

I tried `runtime.Globals.GetVariableNames()` and `runtime.Globals.GetItems()` but both returns empty enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

It's imposible to get the list of variables without reflection (see the picture below). However ruby have way, how to list variables themself ( [Get all local variables or available methods from irb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774947/get-all-local-variables-or-available-methods-from-irb) ).

The selected row is variable created by ruby script.
[image: QuickWatch]

P.S.: I'll let question still unanswered, for someone who will have better solution.